# Android: SQLite DataBase not creating

Tags: android, sqlite

I have used the following code to create  table and insert data into table. The code displays data for only when select statement is within the same file. I have noticed that there is no database in /data/data . Am I missing some thing or the process is actually wrong? If  wrong then what should I do?

```
surgicalmstDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase("surgicalmstDB ", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        surgicalmstDB.setVersion(1);
        surgicalmstDB.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        surgicalmstDB.setLockingEnabled(true);
        surgicalmstDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                " instrument " +
               " (id int,instrumnt TEXT, category TEXT, details TEXT);");

surgicalmstDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                "instrument" +
                " Values (2,'#3 Long Knife Handle ','Cutting and dissecting','Used to cut deeper tissue.');");

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
 String query="SELECT * from instrument WHERE id=2";
                Cursor cursor=surgicalmstDB.rawQuery(query, null);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String title =cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("instrumnt"));
                    String author= cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("category"));
                    String price= cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("details"));
                       txt.setText(title+"-----"+author+"-------"+price);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    surgicalmstDB.close();
```

Comment: so when you are checking the /data/data/ dir, you might have closed your emulator, i suggest you to let the emulator on and then check it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to refer SQLiteOpenHelper instead of hard-coding queries.

Following code will help you

**Employee Model Class**

```
package com.database;

public class Employee {


    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;


    public Employee (){

    }
    // constructor
    public Employee (int id, String name, String _phone_number){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }

    // constructor
    public Employee (String name, String _phone_number){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }
}
```

**SQLite Helper Class**

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employeeDB";


  private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "employee";


private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

**CRUD Operations**

// **Adding new Employee**

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {}
```

// **Getting single Employee**

```
public Contact getEmployee(int id) {}
```

// **Getting All Employees**

```
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {}
```

// **Getting Employees Count**

```
public int getEmployeesCount() {}
```

// **Updating single Employee**

```
public int updateEmployee(Employee employee) {}
```

// **Deleting single Employee**

```
public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {}
```

**Inserting new Record**

```
public void addemployee(Employee employee) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, employee.getName()); 
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, employee.getPhoneNumber()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

**Reading Row(s)**

```
public Contact getEmployee(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Employee employee= new Employee(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return employee;
}
```

**Getting All Employees**

```
public List<Contact> getAllEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Employee employee= new Employee();
            employee.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            employee.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            employee.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));

            employeeList.add(employee);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

       return employeeList;
}
```

**Get All Employees Count**

```
 public int getEmployeesCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

**Updating Record**

```
public int updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, employee.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, employee.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(employee.getID()) });
}
```

**Deleting Record**

```
public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(employee.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```